# Catch the query, which runs on any php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 files, one from the database connection, and the other with querys!
I want to save all queries that are executed in any php file!
Maybe they will help me! maybe Something in the connection file that catches all queries that run.
If you need more details of what I want, just ask.
Thanks

Comment: You could simply write the queries in a .log file after they are executed.

Comment: @BenoitF I in the official project have over 100,000 lines! I need something simpler not to waste days! But thanks

Comment: I didn't try anything! wanted to try what they said in a comment.   "you can activate logging these message to a log file, by activating "Write SQL log to file" in the same dialog."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mysqlnd_qc_get_normalized_query_trace_log ( void ) : array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqlnd-qc-get-normalized-query-trace-log.php) function

or you can configure a log for the MySQL queries.

Comment: Your solution works! But isn't there a solution that doesn't have to touch the querys? I have hundreds of queries on my official project! I wanted some solution that would avoid me touching the querys!Thanks

Comment: You can configure a gobal_query log in MySQL but it will log all database queries.
Are you using a framework?

Comment: I use Heidisql, but what kind of frameworks are you talking about?

Comment: PHP framework (LARAVEL, CODEIGNITER ...) because many frameworks provide a simple way to log MySQL executed queries.

Comment: O ok, I don't use any then

Comment: you can activate logging these message to a log file, by activating "Write SQL log to file" in the same dialog.

Comment: how do you do it? any links? that splits or so?